# add a string to the name of several .pdf file in Terminal in MacOS

Tags: macos, terminal, file-rename

Using Terminal in MacOS, what is the command to add a particular string to the name of several .pdf file. E.g.: if I have

```
firstfile.pdf
anotherfile.pdf
documentthree.pdf
```

I want them all to be renamed

```
addedstring_firstfile.pdf
addedstring_anotherfile.pdf
addedstring_documentthree.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(don't have mac os so didn't test on it).

```
for file in *.pdf
do
   mv "$file" "string_$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13. I changed a little your code and it worked!